# Setting a slicer to the value of a variable using VBA macro (Excel)

Tags: excel, vba

This is a very trivial question for the experts out here :)

I'm trying to set a slicer to the value of a variable using a macro. I've declared a String variable.

```
Dim ProductName As String
'+Some code here to assign a value to ProductName (value of a cell)
ActiveWorkbook.SlicerCaches("Slicer_Name1").VisibleSlicerItemsList = Array( _
            "[Team Project].[Project Node Name].&[ProductName]")
```

That obviously does not work and I didn't expect it to but I can't figure out how I can have it treat ProductName as a variable and not a literal.

The rest of the code is fine as I can successfully set the slicer by specifying a product name without using a variable.

```
ActiveWorkbook.SlicerCaches("Slicer_Name1").VisibleSlicerItemsList = Array( _
            "[Team Project].[Project Node Name].&[Bedsheets]")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Stick the variable out of the string

```
Dim ProductName As String
ActiveWorkbook.SlicerCaches("Slicer_Name1").VisibleSlicerItemsList = Array( _
            "[Team Project].[Project Node Name].&[" & ProductName & "]" )
```

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't work. Run-time error '1004': The item could not be found in the OLAP Cube. It does exist though because if I specify that product name instead of using a variable it works.

Comment: Found the issue. That was missing an & before [" & ProductName. Using this worked like a charm. Thanks! ActiveWorkbook.SlicerCaches("Slicer_Name1").VisibleSlicerItemsList = Array( _
            "[Team Project].[Project Node Name].&[" & ProductName & "]" )

Comment: @Predator might be that I forgot a `&`, I have updated the code give it a try again.